# Creating a Bracketed Sales Commission Calculator with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a calculator using javascript syntax for a realtor client. She wants to use it to show her clients what her commission amount would be. Here's the parameters she gave me. They are bracketed (like income taxes):

- 0.575% up to $100,000
- any amount in excess of $100k, up to $1m is charged at 0.5%
- any amount in excess of $1m is charged at 0.25%

Therefore:

- The first $100k is $575
- The first $1m is $5075 ($575 for the $100k plus $4500 for the next $900k)

Here is my code, where the input is x.

```
(function(){
    if(x <= 100000) return x*0.00575;
    if(x > 100000 && < 1000000) return ((x-100000)*0.005+575);
    if(x >= 1000000) return ((x-1000000)*0.0025+5075);
})();
```

Is this correct? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What error do you get? or what result?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what form you want you code to be in, but I think you have made three mistakes:

1. You have used a 'self-executing function' (also known as an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) `(function(){ ... })();` instead of simple function definition `function calculateCommission () { ... }`.
2. You haven't given the function definition an argument. You should have `function (x) { ... }` rather than just `function () { ... }`.
3. You are missing an `x` in the second condition. It needs to be `if(x > 100000 && x < 1000000)` rather than `if(x > 100000 && < 1000000)`

i.e. Your logic is mostly correct. It's just impossible to call/use this code. Changing these two things, your code would look like:

```
function calculateCommission(x) {
    if(x <= 100000) return x*0.00575;
    if(x > 100000 && x < 1000000) return ((x-100000)*0.005+575);
    if(x >= 1000000) return ((x-1000000)*0.0025+5075);
}
```

This could then be called as follows:

```
var commission = calculateCommission(4594359345079435)
```